# How to set a number of error with xul like firebug does

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

As the question explains itself i've a button like firebug and i wanted to set there a number when some events happens like firebug doeas when it detects errors on the page.

Does anyone know how to set it?

This is the code of the top button that displays a panel, so i want to set there a number when certains events happens..

```
    <panel id="asv-panel">
              <hbox align="start">          
                <vbox>            
                  <hbox align="center" style="background-color:#ffffff">
                  <image id="asvbutton-panel-icon" width="200px" height="50px" style="margin-left:10px"/>
                  </hbox>             
                  <hbox style="background-color:#fff" id="menuPanelContainer">
                    <html:div style="margin-top:20px;margin-left:20px;width:150px" id="menuLogginInicial">
                      <description value="&asbutton.Signin;"/>            
                      <html:hr/>
                      <image id="asvbutton-logoface" width="50px" height="50px" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="asvbutton.login();"/>
<image id="asvbutton-logogoogle" width="47px" height="45px" style="align:left;cursor:pointer"/>
<image id="asvbutton-logotwitter" width="50px" height="50px" style="align:left;cursor:pointer"/>
                    </html:div>             
                  </hbox>             
                </vbox>
              </hbox>
            </panel>            
            </toolbarbutton>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thousands of pages and samples... the easiest way was creating a div and doing an appendChild to it (old school method) :D

Hope this helps someone.